# What files are needed by Malvern from Github?

Tags: java, github

I am trying to install the Google Java library of files needed to run translate.

I have got to the end of the Authentication section OK. The instructions then make a leap to running Malvern.

What is missing is:
What files do I need to download from Github for Malvern?
How do I download those files from Github? and
Where do I put them on my machine?

I am running Netbeans.

Once those questions are answered, then I expect to be able to run the sample.  I tried downloading the whole project but ended up with over 1000 folders and over 700 files.  I suspect that I only need to download a few files, but I don't know which or where.

I expect anyone who knows something about Malvern and Github should be able to answer these questions. If it isn't obvious already, I don't know about Github or Maven.

[Google Translate API instructions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/translate)

[Edit]  I downloaded the whole project from Github then ran the command "mvn clean compile assembly:single" from the project root and got a build failure.  That step is missing from the Google instructions.  Downloading the project and applying the command resulted in a folder with 8MB files, which seems to be excessive for plugging into a simple API.

I turned on debugging to produce the abridged Malven output below.  It appears that all of the Google API specific files were skipped.

```
    Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-04T07:39:06+12:00)
Maven home: D:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
...

[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[WARNING] The project com.google.cloud:doc-samples:pom:1.0.0 uses prerequisites which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not for non maven-plugin projects. For such purposes you should use the maven-enforcer-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html
[WARNING] The project com.google.cloud:appengine-doc-samples:pom:1.0.0 uses prerequisites which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not for non maven-plugin projects. For such purposes you should use the maven-enforcer-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html
[WARNING] The project com.example.appengine:appengine-channel:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT uses prerequisites which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not for non maven-plugin projects. For such purposes you should use the maven-enforcer-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html
[WARNING] The project com.example.gaefirebaseeventproxy:gaefirebaseeventproxy:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT uses prerequisites which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not for non maven-plugin projects. For such purposes you should use the maven-enforcer-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html
[WARNING] The project com.example.appengine:appengine-firebase-tictactoe:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT uses prerequisites which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not for non maven-plugin projects. For such purposes you should use the maven-enforcer-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html
[WARNING] The project com.example.appengine:appengine-guestbook-objectify:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT uses prerequisites which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not for non maven-plugin projects. For such purposes you should use the maven-enforcer-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html
[WARNING] The project com.example.appengine:appengine-multitenancy:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT uses prerequisites which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not for non maven-plugin projects. For such purposes you should use the maven-enforcer-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html
[WARNING] The project com.example.flexible:flexible-analytics:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT uses prerequisites which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not for non maven-plugin projects. For such purposes you should use the maven-enforcer-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] doc-samples
[INFO] appengine-doc-samples
[INFO] appengine-analytics
[INFO] appengine-appidentity
[INFO] appengine-channel
[INFO] appengine-cloudsql
[INFO] appengine-datastore
[INFO] appengine-datastore-indexes
[INFO] appengine-datastore-indexes-exploding
[INFO] appengine-datastore-indexes-perfect
[INFO] echo
[INFO] gaefirebaseeventproxy
[INFO] appengine-firebase-tictactoe
[INFO] appengine-guestbook-objectify
[INFO] appengine-helloworld
[INFO] appengine-helloworld-newplugins
[INFO] appengine-images
[INFO] appengine-logs
[INFO] appengine-mailgun
[INFO] appengine-mailjet
[INFO] appengine-memcache
[INFO] appengine-multitenancy
[INFO] appengine-oauth2
[INFO] appengine-requests
[INFO] appengine-search
[INFO] appengine-sendgrid
[INFO] appengine-remote-client
[INFO] appengine-remote-server
[INFO] appengine-staticfiles
[INFO] taskqueue-push
[INFO] appengine-twilio
[INFO] appengine-URLFetch
[INFO] appengine-users
[INFO] flexible-analytics
[INFO] async-rest
[INFO] flexible-cloudsql
[INFO] flexible-cloudstorage
[INFO] managed-vms-cron
[INFO] flexible-datastore
[INFO] flexible-disk
[INFO] extendingruntime
[INFO] flexible-helloworld
[INFO] mailgun
[INFO] mailjet
[INFO] memcache
[INFO] managed-vms-sendgrid
[INFO] spark
[INFO] staticfiles
[INFO] twilio
[INFO] bigquery-google-cloud-samples
[INFO] bigquery-rest-samples
[INFO] compute-cmdline
[INFO] compute-error-reporting
[INFO] compute-mailjet
[INFO] compute-sendgrid
[INFO] Google Cloud Datastore Snippets
[INFO] datastore-google-cloud-samples
[INFO] kms-samples
[INFO] language-entities
[INFO] language-google-cloud-samples
```

....

```
[DEBUG]   (f) remoteRepositories = [      id: central
      url: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]
]
[DEBUG]   (f) runOnlyAtExecutionRoot = false
[DEBUG]   (s) siteDirectory = D:\temp\java-docs-samples-master\target\site
[DEBUG]   (f) skipAssembly = false
[DEBUG]   (s) tarLongFileMode = warn
[DEBUG]   (s) tempRoot = D:\temp\java-docs-samples-master\target\archive-tmp
[DEBUG]   (s) workDirectory = D:\temp\java-docs-samples-master\target\assembly\work
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] doc-samples ........................................ FAILURE [  1.539 s]
[INFO] appengine-doc-samples .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-analytics ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-appidentity .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-channel .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-cloudsql ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-datastore ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-datastore-indexes ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-datastore-indexes-exploding .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-datastore-indexes-perfect ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] echo ............................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] gaefirebaseeventproxy .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-firebase-tictactoe ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-guestbook-objectify ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-helloworld ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-helloworld-newplugins .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-images ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-logs ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-mailgun .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-mailjet .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-memcache ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-multitenancy ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-oauth2 ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-requests ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-search ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-sendgrid ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-remote-client ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-remote-server ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-staticfiles .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] taskqueue-push ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-twilio ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-URLFetch ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] appengine-users .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] flexible-analytics ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] async-rest ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] flexible-cloudsql .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] flexible-cloudstorage .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] managed-vms-cron ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] flexible-datastore ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] flexible-disk ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] extendingruntime ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] flexible-helloworld ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] mailgun ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] mailjet ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] memcache ........................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] managed-vms-sendgrid ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] spark .............................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] staticfiles ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] twilio ............................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] bigquery-google-cloud-samples ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] bigquery-rest-samples .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] compute-cmdline .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] compute-error-reporting ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] compute-mailjet .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] compute-sendgrid ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Google Cloud Datastore Snippets .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] datastore-google-cloud-samples ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] kms-samples ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] language-entities .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] language-google-cloud-samples ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] cloud-logging-samples .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] logging-google-cloud-samples ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] monitoring-google-cloud-samples .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] cloud-monitoring-samples ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] cloud-monitoring-v3-samples ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] pubsub-google-cloud-samples ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] spanner-google-cloud-samples ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] speech-google-cloud-samples ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] storage-google-cloud-samples ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] storage-json-api ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] transfersample ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] storage-xml-cmdline-sample ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Example for Google Cloud Storage using OAuth 2.0 Service Accounts on Google App Engine SKIPPED
[INFO] taskqueue-defer-sample ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] translate .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] translate-google-cloud-samples ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] unittests-appengine-local-testing-samples .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] vision-google-cloud-samples ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] vision-face-detection .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] vision-label ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] vision-landmark-detection .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] vision-text ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.548 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-19T09:45:13+12:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default-cli) on project doc-samples: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default-cli) on project doc-samples: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:356)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.io.AssemblyReadException: No assembly descriptors found.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.io.DefaultAssemblyReader.readAssemblies(DefaultAssemblyReader.java:206)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:352)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: It's maven not malvern. There are links for how to download and install in the page you link to.

Comment: I have followed the instructions and installed Maven.  That isn't the problem.  I am trying to use Maven to run the Google Translate API.  To do that I think I need to download selected files from Github into the right folder on my machine and then run Maven.  The instructions don't tell me which files to download or where they go.

Comment: Maven will download the libraries automatically. Just follow the instructions.

Comment: The instruction say: mvn clean compile assembly:single, so I ran that command and got a build error which mentions the POM file.  I suspect I need to download the POM file and put it somewhere.  As far as I can tell, the instructions are missing a key step.

Comment: I found some general instructions here: http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/09/maven-tips-and-tricks-using-github/ but they are 8 years old and probably out of date.

Comment: If you tell us the exact build error you get we can maybe help.

Comment: The error message is:  "The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory."      I don't have a project directory and I don't have a POM. I don't know where the project directory should be, what it should be called, and what should be in it.

Comment: Ah, ok. Download the project first: on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples use the green clone or download button and use "Download ZIP". Then run maven in the root directory of the project.

Comment: Hi Henry <br>  That seemed to work right up until the end when Malven spat errors. I can't insert or add links here so I have added links to the OP to show the Malven output.  I am limited to two links.  <br>  It actually looks like it has skipped downloading all of the Google API specific files.  The exact files I need to run the API.  So this is one step forward, one step back.

Comment: That failed already at the very beginning. You can try to cd into the "translate" directory (if this is the only module you are interested in) and run maven there.

Comment: I went to this page:  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples
and downloaded the zip of the project.

I extracted this to D:\temp\ to create the directory:
D:\temp\java-docs-samples-master\ and all the sub directories.

I went to the D:\temp\java-docs-samples-master\translate\ directory and ran the command:  
mvn clean compile assembly:single

The result was a successful build.  The above actions are the critical instructions missing from the Google instructions.

Comment: Looking at the instructions here:  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/translate
the next problem I have is that running the api from the command line is no use to me.  

I found sample code and a library file in these directories: D:\temp\java-docs-samples-master\translate\cloud-client\src\main\java\com\example\translate\QuickstartSample.java
and D:\temp\java-docs-samples-master\translate\target\translate-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

I am going to import those into Netbeans and see if I can run the sample code.

Comment: I have found a guide here: http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenBestPractices for importing a Maven project into Netbeans.  I will give that a go.

Comment: Hi  So I find that Netbeans can read Maven projects directly.  I import the Maven project into Netbeans and immediately get errors.  All of the files in the Modules folder report "some dependency artifacts are not in the local repository".  Although the Maven project builds without error, Netbeans spits it out.  I feel that I am just one step away from error free compiling in Netbeans so I can import the API into my code.  I have no idea what that next step should be.